# How to access delegates in different ListViews in QML or Javascript

Tags: javascript, python, qt, qml

I am QML newbie. I am trying to understand how to access selected delegates in ListView
For instance I have the following main.qml

```js
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Controls 2.5
import QtQuick.Window 2.15
Window {
    width : 640
    height : 700
    visible : true
    title : qsTr("Hello World")
    Rectangle {
        id : rect_A
        anchors.left : parent.left
        width : 300
        height : 500
        border.color : "black"
        border.width : 2
        ListView {
            id : view_A
            anchors.fill : parent
            spacing : 10
            model : 5
            delegate : comp_1
        }
    }
    Rectangle {
        id : rect_B
        anchors.right : parent.right
        width : 300
        height : 300
        border.color : "black"
        border.width : 2
        ListView {
            id : view_B
            anchors.fill : parent
            spacing : 10
            model : 5
            clip : true
            delegate : comp_1
        }
    }
    Component {
        id : comp_1
        Row {
            id : row_1
            spacing : 10
            CheckBox {
                id : checkBox
                Text {
                    text : index
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to achieve the following behavior: when I check or uncheck the checkbox on the left, the appropriate checkbox on the right does the same.

I'm trying to understand how to address selected delegates and change their properties.

Could you help me please? I have a feeling that this should be easy but I am missing something fundamental.

Answer (score 0):

This is usually done via a model defined in C++ / Python, with a role that tracks the checked state.
here is a simple example with `ListModel`:

```js
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
import QtQml.Models

Item{
    ListModel{id: checkable_model
        ListElement {
            checked: false
        }
        ListElement {
            checked: false
        }
        ListElement {
            checked: false
        }
        ListElement {
            checked: false
        }
    }
    Rectangle {
        id : rect_A
        anchors.left : parent.left
        width : 300
        height : 500
        border.color : "black"
        border.width : 2
        ListView {
            id : view_A
            anchors.fill : parent
            spacing : 10
            model : checkable_model
            delegate : MyDelegate{}
        }
    }
    Rectangle {
        id : rect_B
        anchors.right : parent.right
        width : 300
        height : 300
        border.color : "black"
        border.width : 2
        ListView {
            id : view_B
            anchors.fill : parent
            spacing : 10
            model : checkable_model
            clip : true
            delegate : MyDelegate{}
        }
    }
}

// MyDelegate.qml
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
Row {
    required property var model
    
    id : row_1
    spacing : 10
    CheckBox {
        id : checkBox
        checked: model.checked
        onCheckedChanged:{model.checked = checked}
        Text {
            text : model.index
        }
    }
}
```

[You can try it here](https://stephenquan.github.io/qmlonline/?zcode=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)